# Unable to Drop a table after a WITH statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a `WITH` statement that collects the data I want. What I want to do is to be able to do a `SELECT` from different parts of my `WITH` and `INSERT` that result into a destination table.

Here is a simplified version of my long query:

```
WITH Active AS (
    --SELECT 1
),
Inactive AS (
    --SELECT 2
),
Churn AS (
    --SELECT 3
)
--Drop destination table if exists
IF OBJECT_ID('DestinationTable', 'u') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE DestinationTable;

SELECT Active.Name, Inactive.Name,Churn.Id
INTO DestinationTable
FROM Active a
JOIN Inactive i ON a.Id = i.Id
JOIN Churn c ON a.Id = c.Id;
```

But *Sql Server* does not allow an `IF` statement directly after a `WITH`. I do not want to move the `IF` before my `WITH` because then it will be likely that my destination table be empty for a long time.

**Simple version of my question:**

How can I write a `SELECT` from a `WITH` statement into another table?

Comment: Why not just truncate your DestinationTable instead of dropping it and recreating it? Would be much simpler and less resource intensive.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to maintain "recent" cached results from the long query for use elsewhere. You could add a column to `DestinationTable` to record a serial number that you increase each time you run your "long query". After that finishes, delete all rows with any lower serial number. Code using the data should always have access to one complete set identified by a common serial number. (Mind your transactions as needed for your application.)

Answer (score 2):

Because it is compulsory to use with statement result follow by with statement.
Any other statement except with result not allowed.

You can write your drop statement above the with statement

Comment: So I should just write the results into temp tables instead?

Comment: write drop above with

Comment: I do not want to move the IF before my WITH because then it will be likely that my destination table be empty for a long time.

Comment: if you write after with as tried also become null for long if no any result in with statement

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your last comment.

Comment: mean in your current code it also get null always and then fill from with statement

Comment: Yes it does. But in my version it does not stay unavailable for a long time. Maybe I should just go on with creating temp tables and then remove them at the end of the query?

Answer (score 2):

Just restructure it like this:

```
--Drop destination table if exists
IF OBJECT_ID('DestinationTable', 'u') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE DestinationTable

;WITH Active AS (
    --SELECT 1
),
Inactive AS (
    --SELECT 2
),
Churn AS (
    --SELECT 3
)

SELECT Active.Name, Inactive.Name,Churn.Id
INTO DestinationTable
FROM Active a
JOIN Inactive i ON a.Id = i.Id
JOIN Churn c ON a.Id = c.Id;
```

The scope of the CTE means it needs to be used in the statement immediately after it's declaration.

Otherwise you need some other staging area to handle the load before you replace the destination table.

Comment: But would this not leave the `DestinationTable` unavailable for the while `WITH` is running?

Comment: Not just empty, it wouldn't exist. You could create it first rather than using INTO.

Comment: Yes, by "unavailable", I mean non-existing. So do you think it would be better if, instead of using `WITH`, I create temp tables for each and then remove them at the end? This way I can use `IF OBJECT_ID` without a problem.

Comment: @Disasterkid it depends on where you are using this. For example, you can't use a #TempTable in a view. IMHO TempTables and table variables give you more flexibility but CTE's are better for editing the data inline.