# Using IF EXISTS with a CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to check if a CTE table has record or null. But I always get error message 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'' for the SQL below. Now there is no matching record in ADMISSION_OUTSIDE TABLE. The result of the SQl should print 'NOT OK'. Thanks,

```
WITH ADMISSION_OUTSIDE AS 
(   .....
.....
)

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ADMISSION_OUTSIDE)
PRINT 'OK'
ELSE PRINT 'NOT OK'
```

Comment: a cte should be followed by `SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE` statements

Comment: Maybe you are doing a bit of confusing here. That's not the corret syntax and porbably not the corret usage of a CTE. Maybe you just want to put the content of the query inside your CTE in a table variable. Note after the command following the CTE definition you don't have the CTE in scope

Comment: Are you just printing to debug the query?  Or are you intending to also select data from it?

Comment: The benefit of a CTE over a subquery is mostly that it's resultset can be reused in a SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE statement. Like f.e. in Prdp's answer. But perhaps you should look at what can be achieved with a [cursor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx).

Answer (score 22):

From [**`MSDN`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms175972.aspx)

> A CTE must be followed by a single SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE
>   statement that references some or all the CTE columns

It can be re-written like this

```
WITH ADMISSION_OUTSIDE AS 
(   .....
.....
)
SELECT 'OK' WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ADMISSION_OUTSIDE)
UNION ALL
SELECT 'NOT OK' WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ADMISSION_OUTSIDE)
```

Here is a demo

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT 1 as a WHERE 1=0
)
SELECT 'OK' WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM CTE)
UNION ALL
SELECT 'NOT OK' WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM CTE)
```

**Result :** `NOT OK`

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT 1 as a WHERE 1=1
)
SELECT 'OK' WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM CTE)
UNION ALL
SELECT 'NOT OK' WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM CTE)
```

**Result :** `OK`

Comment: I got blank value.

Comment: @Ice - Added demo also

Comment: If you don't like the UNION you can use a case statement instead, e.g. `SELECT case when exists (SELECT * FROM CTE) then 'OK' else 'NOT OK' end `

Answer (score 6):

I think this is also one simplest way to check the value existence and perform the operation.

```
WITH ADMISSION_OUTSIDE AS 
(   .....
.....
)
SELECT CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(1) tot 
                  FROM ADMISSION_OUTSIDE) > 0 THEN 'OK' ELSE 'NOT OK' END
```

Comment: EXISTS will stop reading data when it finds a match. COUNT will read all rows corresponding to the predicate. In general EXISTS is more efficient.

Comment: Do you think it's not suitable answer for  `check if a CTE table has record or null` ?

Answer (score 4):

A bit hacky but you could do something like this:

```
declare @x bit

;WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT 1 As 'column1'
)
SELECT @x = ISNULL(column1,0) from cte

If @x=1
begin
...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Because it is compulsory to use with statement result follow by with statement. Any other statement except with result not allowed.

Please refer for more information:[Unable to Drop a table after a WITH statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39572135/unable-to-drop-a-table-after-a-with-statement/39572164#39572164)

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server returns that error message ("Incorrect syntax") because it's not a valid statement.

A Common Table Expression (CTE) is not by itself a separate statement. It's an *expression* which is part of another statement, either a SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE or CREATE VIEW statement.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx