# Using WITH CTE in IF NOT EXISTS

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression, not-exists

I have a table-valued function that selects rows as part of a CTE, and I then want to perform a different select/insert into the returned table if no rows were selected in the CTE:

```
WITH myCte AS (SELECT * FROM abc WHERE xyz = 123)

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM myCte)
BEGIN
    ...
END
```

However I'm getting a syntax error whenever I go to use CTE tables in the NOT EXISTS condition. My myCte is a lot more complex than the example, so it will be awkward to place the whole query in the condition.

How can I use the CTE result in the condition check?

Comment: Already answered at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39576785/using-if-exists-with-a-cte

Comment: Not related - I think complex queries is a good sign to move this logic to the application code. Database responsibility reading and writing data onl  - and not processing it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare your [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) in the context where it will be used and it can only be used for the statement that follows `with`. If you want to use the results multiple times, you can either repeat the common table expression multiple times, or you can use a table variable or temporary table to hold the results instead.

```
WITH myCte AS (SELECT * FROM abc WHERE xyz = 123)

select * 
into #myTempTable
from myCte

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #myTempTable)
BEGIN
    ...
END
```