# SQL Server, CTE with IF EXISTS, then update existing values, else insert

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

I am trying to change my current query to say, if x exists, then update values, otherwise just insert into table.

Right now my query is something like

```
with t1 as
(
    select * from table
)
insert into existingTable
```

How do I add an `IF EXISTS`, then `UPDATE` values, if not `INSERT INTO`.

I am trying not to have the `WITH` statement twice because it is very long.

Any ideas?

Comment: Use a SQL Merge statement:  https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1704/using-merge-in-sql-server-to-insert-update-and-delete-at-the-same-time/

Comment: Maybe take a look at MERGE? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Also, don't get hung up on a CTE for this. There are other ways. I don't see the value in using it since you aren't going to update the base tables through the CTE itself i don't suspect... given you also want an insert. Perhaps a temp table or some other logic would be better. can you post the actual CTE code?

Comment: Have you ever heard of `MERGE`??

Comment: thanks... I didn't know about MERGE.  looks promising. also @scsimon, you are correct, probably don't need to use cte, a temptable might work just fine. let me try that. thanks!

Comment: The question was specific to using it with at CTE @TabAlleman

Comment: @scsimon the solution in the duplicate can be used with or without a CTE.  You yourself said "don't get hung up on a CTE for this".   It really doesn't change anything whether a CTE is involved or not.

Comment: Yes, I said you may not need to use a CTE, but can you show me how you can run an `IF EXISTS UPDATE ELSE INSERT` following a `CTE` @TabAlleman ?

Comment: I see what you mean.  For that part of it, here is the duplicate:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39576785/using-if-exists-with-a-cte Instead of IF, you have to `UPDATE WHERE EXISTS()` and `INSERT WHERE NOT EXISTS()`   But a question that combines two duplicate questions isn't a new question.

Comment: I disagree with your last comment because  it conflicts with the definition of duplicate but that is just my two cents. I feel if that was the case 2/3 of the questions on stack overflow could be removed @TabAlleman

Comment: basically based on the replies on this thread I was able to solve my issue.  I previously saw those other threads and I couldn't figure it out.... so this question helped me!  thanks!!